# SQL Type Convervsion in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I admit that this may be prompted by not having an intimate knowledge of SQL, but I have a Dataset with an integer column named Year. If I write the SQL query:

```
selectstring = 
  @"SELECT Author, 
           Title,
           Year, 
           Keywords, 
           Location 
      FROM Books 
     WHERE Year = iYear";
```

where iYear has previously been declared as an integer, running a cursor over the SQL statement tells me that both Year and iYear are strings. Why does this type conversion take place?
  This is an easy to solve problem here but when one is working with F types with a lot of digits after the decimal point it would seem to be harder unless simple casting works.

Comment: Can you clarify - how exactly you're executing this query from c# environment and how you're getting the results?

Comment: What do you mean "running a cursor over the SQL statement"? What c# code are you using to loop through the results, and how are you checking the types? More information would be extremely useful here.

Comment: I tend to believe that he refers to the fact that if you move the cursor effectively over the string the content appears to be a string, which obviously, not doubt, is a string.

@Silenius If I understand well, do you want to inject your variable value in your SQL sequence?

Comment: I apologize for the lateness in responding. The code is being written in Visual Studio 2015 w/ SQL Server Express running. I have since noticed that the color of the iYear variable is that of a string and not a variable. This is, I guess, because of my hazy knowledge of working with literals as Andy Korneyev sort of pointed out.  I thank you all for your time and effort in looking at this.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
selectstring = "SELECT Author, Title, Year, Keywords, Location FROM Books WHERE Year = " + iYear;
```

Comment: Have you ever heard about sql injection? And by the way - this doesn't attempts to answer *actual* OP's question. Have you read the question precisely?

Comment: Yes I know about SQL injection but this application is really a purely local one siting on my PC not meant to be shared on a network. Baring an outside attack I assume injection is not a problem. When this thing gets done I hope to redo it with string builder to eliminate the problem.